# Confirmation prompt when trying to swipe to pop current viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have to make sure the user knows he will lose the modifications in an edit view controller before the pop action will be performed. For that, I am creating a closure that will return true/false corresponding to the decision if the pop should continue or should be prevented.

**The problem** is when swiping with a gesture to pop I am encountering an unexpected behavior: viewWillDisappear is called, but the controller is not disappearing. viewDidDisappear is never called. Also, the screen is freezed, but I am able to press the tabBar items to jump back in another controller. When coming back to the current tab item, the view controller is already popped but eventually, I will encounter other freezes.

Can you see any solution for this? Thanks!

// Code from the custom navigation controller

```
var popHandler: (() -> Bool)?

override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?
{
    guard self.popHandler?() != false else
    {
        return nil
    }
    self.popHandler = nil
    return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
}
```

//Code from the edit controller

```
func setupPopHandler() {
    guard let navigationController = self.navigationController as? MyCustomNavController else {
        return
    }
       
    navigationController.popHandler = { [weak self] in
        
        guard let self = self else { return true }
        
        if self.hasChangedFields() && self.hasUnsavedWork == true {
            
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "You have unsaved changes", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { action in
                // Call save method which will pop the VC after saving
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
                self.hasUnsavedWork = false
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            
            return false
            
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of overriding `popViewController`, you probably want to create a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and add it to your navController.  It should allow you to stop the pop operation and put up your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a working solution. If you cancel out `popViewController` when it's triggered by `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` it will really mess with the display queue. The trick is to use a custom UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer IF `popHandler` is set.

```
/// Custom UINavigationController that can block a dismiss via a set `popHandler`
/// - Important: `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` will be set to `true` when a viewController is dismissed.
open class BlockerNavigationController: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    private var gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer?
    
    /// Return `true` if dismissal is allowed
    open var popHandler: (() -> Bool)? {
        didSet {
            if popHandler != nil {
                interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
                gesture?.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
                gesture?.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    /// handle edge swipe cases
    @objc private func onEdgeSwipe(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // handle dismissals via edge swipes
        if gesture.state == .began {
            if popHandler?() == false
            {
                return
            }
            self.popHandler = nil
            if viewControllers.count > 1 {
                viewControllers.last?.dismiss(animated: true)
            } else {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    open override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?
    {
        // handle dismissals via `dismiss`
        guard self.popHandler?() != false else
        {
            return nil
        }
        self.popHandler = nil
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
    
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        gesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onEdgeSwipe(gesture:)))
        gesture?.delegate = self
        gesture?.edges = .left
        gesture?.isEnabled = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
    }
}
```